# Behaviors with forms in yii

Tags: php, yii

I have a [Yii behavior](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/44/behaviors-events/#hh1), that adds some custom fields with condition

_form.php

```
$form->attachbehavior('users', new DirectoriesBehavior);

// return part of form
echo $form->getDirectory(array('sysName' => 'users', 'useDefaultValue' => true));

// Other form parts (default for yii)
echo $form->labelEx($model, 'name');
```

`DirectoriesBehavior::getDirectory()` build HTML form part with `<select>` or `<input>` etc. fields.

But how can I send name/id of the form to my behavior?

After rendering it looks like

```
<form method="" id="myForm">
    <!--BEHAVIORS CONTENT-->
    <select>
        <option value="UserId">UserName</option>
    </select>

    <!--Default fields of form-->
    <input type="text" name="myForm[exampleField]" />
</form>
```

And my behaviors content should to looks like

```
<select name="myForm[users]">
    <option>etc</option>
</select>
```

Comment: You solved the problem? or just partially!! please try put the remain question (issue) part clear at the end!!

Answer (score 0):

I resolve this problem:

We can sent $model in _form.php

```
$form->getDirectory(array('model' => $model));
```

in DirectoriesBehavior.php

```
public function getDirectory(array $data)
{
    $this->inputName = get_class($data['model']);
}
```

Also ( for scripts that will be work with this form we can to send ID of the form )

_form.php

```
$form->id;
```